# Shader Resource View analogous in threejs

Tags: three.js, hlsl2glsl

Is there any equivalent method for Shader Resource View in Threejs, 
When I searched on net I found that the equivalent for Shader Resource View in OpenGL is Texture View (glTextureView), But Couldn't find anything in threejs

Comment: It's hard to figure out what you're asking for without more context. Three.js uses GLSL2.0 as its shader language, so anything that works in GLSL2.0 should work in Three.js. Are you looking for a way to sample a texture? If so, you're probably looking for [`texture2D()` which you can read more about here.](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/tutorials/ClockworkCoders/texturing.php)

Comment: Actually Shader Resource View is used in D3D11, It is used to split a YUV texture to Y plane and UV plane